# ''router-outlet' is not a known element - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I've been at this problem for a few hours now. I have tried literally everything but I can't get it to work.

The next error keeps coming up:

```
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

---

Here are my files, which I have reduced to the basic needs for routing:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TafelComponent } from '../tafel/tafel.component';
import { MuurtafelComponent } from '../muurtafel/muurtafel.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tafel', component: TafelComponent },
  { path: 'muurtafel', component: MuurtafelComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TafelComponent } from './tafel/tafel.component';
import { MuurtafelComponent } from './muurtafel/muurtafel.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  exports: [AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TafelComponent,
    MuurtafelComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
```

---

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Industial Furniture</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Can someone help me with this? Could it be anything outside of the code? (Or is it that I'm overseeing something here?)

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a new Angular project and try the `router-outlet` there and see if it works. If it does, then its something wrong with your code/project, and then you need to compare the project that is working to the one that isn't and see where the differences are. If it doesn't work, then it's something wrong with the installation or the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

In your app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
...,
   imports: [
     AppRoutingModule
    ],

    exports: [AppRoutingModule], // Remove this line
...
})
```

You don't need to export here !

Comment: I have also tried it that way, but it has the same result. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't deeply delve into your code, but I got the same error after rename package + component name. I also checked all my code, but found nothing, I just tried stop CLI and restart. All compiled good and started working. Maybe this will help.

Comment: This! I found and successfully applied exactly the same "solution" when I got this error. In my case, the preceding action was not a package rename, though, but the addition of a reference to another module (unrelated to router-outlet).

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts remove

```
exports: [AppRoutingModule],
```

Also kill the server then run `ng serve` again

Another note that I saw you use

```
HttpModule
```

instead

```
HttpClientModule
```

New version of angular already use `HttpClientModule` so try to use lastest version if you can